# Comunicate to server with different languages

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a server made with nodeJS. And I have created a simple application, that comunícate with the client using socketIO.

I need make possible that the users can connect to this app with other languages (Python, Java...), but I don't know how to make this.

For example, I start the server in xxx.xxx.xxxx:xxx, users can connect to this server with a script, and maintain a communication with him.

Is it possible using SocketIo? What other ways I can follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

There are socket.io clients in different languages too. You just need to google it.

Comment: Yes I see it, but use socket io, is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

So long as all the clients talk with the same protocol it should work. However, you might need to implement the socket.io stuff in each of the target clients if one does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

All languages have their way of connecting to a server, and they don't care what language the server is written in. The important thing is that you transfer the data over a universal format such as JSON (pretty much every language has a library that can parse JSON)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I need a fast communication like using socker io for games.

Comment: Yup that will work. Again, it's up to the different languages to provide the support, not you. You just need to build the functionality in your app to initiate the sockets with whatever client is connecting.